# Align in second equal sign without adding space

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have the following output:
[image]

The code that generates the image above is given below. What I want is to get rid of this extra space in the first line
Any ideas?

```latex
  \begin{align*}
    \alpha \fatsemi (\beta \fatsemi \gamma) &\iff 
    \forall c \in \mathcal C, &\alpha_c \fatsemi (\beta \fatsemi \gamma)_c &=
    \alpha_c \fatsemi (\beta_c \fatsemi \gamma_c)\\& &&=
    (\alpha_c \fatsemi \beta_c) \fatsemi \gamma_c \\& &&= 
    (\alpha_c \fatsemi \beta_c) \fatsemi \gamma_c \\& &&= 
    (\alpha \fatsemi \beta)_c \fatsemi \gamma_c \\
                                            &\iff
    (\alpha \fatsemi \beta) \fatsemi \gamma
  \end{align*}
```

Comment: Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Please provide executable code.  For example, where is `\fatsemi` defined?

Comment: The easy solution is to add one or more && at the beginning of each line and the end of at least one line.  This will shrink  the size of each && gap.

Comment: The `alignat*{2}` environment will add no space.

Answer (score 1):

You want to nest `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\alpha \fatsemi (\beta \fatsemi \gamma)
&\iff 
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  \forall c \in \mathcal C,\ 
  \alpha_c \fatsemi (\beta \fatsemi \gamma)_c
  &=\alpha_c \fatsemi (\beta_c \fatsemi \gamma_c)\\
  &=(\alpha_c \fatsemi \beta_c) \fatsemi \gamma_c \\
  &=(\alpha_c \fatsemi \beta_c) \fatsemi \gamma_c \\
  &=(\alpha \fatsemi \beta)_c \fatsemi \gamma_c
  \end{aligned} \\
&\iff (\alpha \fatsemi \beta) \fatsemi \gamma
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

barbara beeton made me notice in comments that you have a QED marker, so I assume the display ends a proof. In this case you need `\qedhere`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Some words to start the proof
\begin{align*}
\alpha \fatsemi (\beta \fatsemi \gamma)
&\iff 
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  \forall c \in \mathcal C,\ 
  \alpha_c \fatsemi (\beta \fatsemi \gamma)_c
  &=\alpha_c \fatsemi (\beta_c \fatsemi \gamma_c)\\
  &=(\alpha_c \fatsemi \beta_c) \fatsemi \gamma_c \\
  &=(\alpha_c \fatsemi \beta_c) \fatsemi \gamma_c \\
  &=(\alpha \fatsemi \beta)_c \fatsemi \gamma_c
  \end{aligned} \\
&\iff (\alpha \fatsemi \beta) \fatsemi \gamma
\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a comment about the tombstone being dropped onto a separate line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Comment to the wrong answer?

Comment: Yours is the only answer.  The OP has included a tombstone in his display example, but without a clear explication of the problem.  People read your answers, so I figured you could make this a teaching moment,

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh! I hadn't seen it! Added the guess! :-)